# Android Black-Box Viewer (Betaflight)

Tags: betaflight, recommendations, software, smartphone-app, tools

I'm using Speedy Bee (an Android betaflight configurator) a lot on the field for changing settings and tuning.

I use a USB-OTG-Cable for my Android phone to connect to the FC.

But I do miss an Android tool to do a fast check of the BlackBox on the field.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: I know that [RacedroneSoft](https://www.racedronesoft.com/) do BlackBox Viewer for Android.  Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?  I haven't used it myself, but a friend did suggest that I look at it.

Comment: Thnx!! yes! Cool! .. is it clean? So no trojan/Virus? (it's not in play store)

Comment: I haven't used it.  (I don't know enough about what I'm doing yet!)  My friend has though. 
 He said he likes it, and he didn't mention any problems.

Comment: @heavykick It's definitely not always accurate, but it doesn't hurt to scan it at https://virustotal.com